# TYPO3 v11 persistence.storagePid is ignored

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-11.x

I have an TYPO3 Extbase extension with TYPO3 11.
My problem is, that every item is shown.

In my plugin there is a Flexform Field for the storagePid. But the plugin completely ignored this settings and every time lists all items.

How can I tell my extension that it should only load items from the selected page?

I have tried to set this:

```
public function getItems()
{
    $table = 'TABLE';
    $query = $this->itemRepository->createQuery();
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(true);
    return $query->execute();
}
```

But that doesn't help.

This doesn't change anything in the repository

```
public function initializeObject() {
  /** @var Typo3QuerySettings $querySettings */
  $querySettings = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Typo3QuerySettings::class);
  $querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(TRUE);
  $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you mean what you set in the default field `tt_content.pages` and `tt_content.recursive`.

Here is an example how to get the page IDs from the fields: https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/11.5/typo3/sysext/felogin/Classes/Controller/AbstractLoginFormController.php#L35-L50

And then you would set that for your Extbase query:

```php
$querySettings = $this->myRepository->createQuery()->getQuerySettings();
$querySettings->setStoragePageIds(...);
```

---

*Background:*

Here is a great write-up how naming a Flexform field `persistence.storagePid` would give you that, too https://www.derhansen.de/2016/02/how-extbase-determines-storagepid.html

Comment: I dont have Code like ```plugin.tx_myext_myplugin.persistence.storagePid ={$plugin.tx_myext_myplugin.persistence.storagePid}``` in my Extension. Is there a way to set the selected oages in the repository?

Comment: Maybe, but not dynamically. You would set it in the query. See my comment for that.

Comment: I just figured out, that ```$item = $this->itemRepository->findAll();``` in the listAction solved my problem.